# Disable stdout in popen process

Tags: c, pipe, stdout

I'm using `popen` function in C to run external program in my project. As far as I know `popen` creates `pipe` and `pipe` is buffer-blocking process. The problem is my program, that runs in `pipe` produces a lot of output.

I don't need this output but I don't read it, so my process is stick on buffer overflowing.

My question: is there any way to totally disable output of process? I tried `stdbuf -o0 %my_command%` but it didn't help.

Comment: Use the second argument. Set `type="w"`. Then the subprocess will output to the terminal and you can redirect all output as usual using `> /dev/null`. If that is not acceptable then you would have to learn how to use underlying functions `pipe`, `dup2`, `fork`, `exec`,